# What is the exact difference between "ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated" and "ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My apologies in advance if my question sounds primary, I am very new at QA and Selenium.

What is the exact difference between:

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                    (By.xpath("//a[text()='Show advanced settings...']"))).click();
```

and

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated
                    (By.xpath("//a[text()='Show advanced settings...']"))).click();
```

I had a look at [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) but did not figure it out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The visibilityOfElmementLocated checks to see if the element is present and also visible. To check visibility it makes sure the element has a height and width greater than 0.

The presenceOfElementLocated just checks the dom to see if it can locate an element no matter its visibility.

Source:
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-

visibilityOf
public static ExpectedCondition visibilityOf(WebElement element)
An expectation for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible. **Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.
Parameters:**

Comment: so if an element is present but not visible we cannot click on it but if it is visible and present we can do it, right?

Comment: Correct. Unless you use a javascript click.

Comment: what about javascript click? do I need to write code in javascript?!! :(

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  Object element = enterelementhere(driver);
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: Also, if you think my answer is correct please select it as so. Thank you.

Comment: Why do I need this javascrip? can't I just do it by regular .click() as I showed in my question?