# what is the exact difference between "ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated" and "element.isDisplayed()"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My apologies in advance if my question sounds primary, I am very new at QA and Selenium.

What is the exact difference between:

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                    (By.xpath("//a[text()='Show advanced settings...']"))).click();
```

and

```
 element.isDisplayed();
```

I believe when the second one returns true we can click on the web element but I am not sure about the first one, I read about it [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementWithText-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.lang.String-) but not sure yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the exact difference between "ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated" and "ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242882/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-expectedconditions-visibilityofelementloca)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first one is a wait and will wait until that condition is true.

Your second one return a true or false based upon if the element is displayed.

Reading your other question and this one it may be easier for you to write what you are trying to do, so we can help you with that.

[What is the exact difference between "ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated" and "ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242882/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-expectedconditions-visibilityofelementloca/33243103#33243103)

Thank you