# visibilityOfElementLocated Vs visibilityOf

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When i tried to run below code, `visibilityOfElementLocated` works perfectly fine and webdriver waits for the element with given time.

```
dr.get("http://www.seleniumframework.com/Practiceform/");
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(dr,30);
WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Element5")));
```

but the same way if i use `visibilityOf`, it gives me

> NoSuchElementException

```
WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(dr.findElement(By.linkText("Element3"))));
```

Can you explain me why i am getting this exception?

Answer (score 20):

> but the same way if i use "visibilityOf",it gives me NoSuchElementException

Actually, you are getting `Exception` by this line of code **`dr.findElement(By.linkText("Element3"))`**, in your provided code this line will execute first and if element will be find then [`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) callable will execute.

**FYI, [`WebDriver.findElement()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) either throws exception or returns a [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).**

**[`visibilityOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) Vs  [`visibilityOf`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)** :-

- [`visibilityOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) is used for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a **page and visible**. Means it uses `By` object instead of `WebElement` object with callable function to find that element first then check that element is visible or not.
- [`visibilityOf`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) is used for checking that an element, **known to be present on the DOM of a page**, is visible. Means you have already found that element and just  check only for that visibility.

Comment: this answer helped out a ton. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242882/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-expectedconditions-visibilityofelementloca):

> **visibilityOf**: Does not check for **presence** of the **element** as the error explains it.
>
> **visibilityOfElementLocated**: Checks to see if the element is **present** and also **visible**. To check visibility, it makes sure that the element has a height and width greater than 0.