# Why this code showing error while the button near right after the pass-code field?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I have tried to locate the button and click on it by the code given below.Other method which I have used also comment on the bottom of the code.

Error saying that Submit button in the end of the code was not able to locate by the code.
Why these error showing while the button is able to locate and click?Please help me to find a solution for this..

```
WebElement unfield =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-name']"));       
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(unfield).click();     
unfield.clear();
unfield.sendKeys("test");      
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-password']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-password']")).sendKeys("test");
WebElement test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='SIGN IN'])[1]/following::button[1]"));
Actions actions_signinclick = new Actions(driver);
actions_signinclick .moveToElement(test).click().build().perform();
//this will display in next page
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='user-passcode']")));    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user-passcode']")).click();                                                                                       
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user-passcode']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user-passcode']")).sendKeys("1234");      
WebDriverWait submit_button = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
submit_button.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@_ngcontent-wks-c3=''][text()='SUBMIT']/self::BUTTON")));          
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@_ngcontent-wks-c3=''][text()='SUBMIT']/self::BUTTON")).click();

    /*WebElement test1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@_ngcontent-wks-c3=''][text()='SUBMIT']/self::BUTTON"));
    Actions actions_submitclick = new Actions(driver);
    actions_submitclick .moveToElement(test1).click().build().perform();*/
```

Error shows as follows,

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //BUTTON[@_ngcontent-wks-c3=''][text()='SUBMIT']/self::BUTTON (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)

Answer (score 2):

```
submit_button.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@_ngcontent-wks-c3=''][text()='SUBMIT']/self::BUTTON")));          
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@_ngcontent-wks-c3=''][text()='SUBMIT']/self::BUTTON")).click();
```

AFAIU you are looking for the difference of the above two lines,

In first line **visibilityOfElementLocated** is used to check whether element is present on the DOM and also check whether visibility.To check visibility, it makes sure that the element has a height and width greater than 0. 
In your case maybe element is present on the DOM but no visibility, Hence you are getting the exception.
[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038485/visibilityofelementlocated-vs-visibilityof/42038743)

In second line, you are just clicking the element present on the DOM, so its getting passed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have refereed your link too.But it is not working when I tried to locate it directly(driver.findElement(By.xpath......),it also throwing an error message saying "unable to locate the element".Thats why i have tried the commented code above.Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: which browser are you using? have you tried css ? Are your xpath evaluates correctly when tried on the browse?

Comment: There was a error in Xpath,I have rewrite it and tried the code,works fine now.Thanku so much

Comment: Thanks again.As you are senior in the industry,I would be grateful if you could add some advises here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57584908/recommadation-about-the-code-construction