# Selenium webdriver wait, Element not clickable exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am using selenium webdriver for chrome.
I am testing an web application with lot of ajax contents so after login into the application it will take some seconds to load ajax content in home page.

I've used explicit wait after login to wait until finding the element. But it fails mostly. I've given 25 seconds to wait but it fails after 4 seconds of wait .
The error is ,...

```
Unknown error: Element <a href="/ls/create_new" class="ajax addDashButton hasLink">...</a> is not clickable at point (144, 223).
```

Other element would receive the click: 
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.78)
  (

My code is ..

```
public class login {
    WebDriver driver;

  @Test
  public void f() {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "filepath/chromedriver");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("URL");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();

      driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("username");
      driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
      driver.findElement(By.className("login")).click();

      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);

      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Create New App")));
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create New App")).click();
  }
}
```

This is just part of my code ..What is the correct way to use webdriver wait. TY

Comment: I think its able to find the element, just that the element it finds is not clickable as you try. Thats what the logs read.

Comment: Can you please share your site url?

Comment: The url is demo.vizru.com

Answer (score 2):

Intead of using **presenceOfElementLocated**, try once **visibilityOfElementLocated** .

- visibilityOfElementLocated: it checks for element should be visible and present.
- presenceOfElementLocated: It just checks for element is present in the DOM or not.

for more information use can check the below link-
[What is the exact difference between "ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated" and "ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242882/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-expectedconditions-visibilityofelementloca)

Comment: yes .. now it seems to be working thank you . i have one more doubt .. can i declare webdriver wait time common in all testcases . how can i use ( WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);) this method in parent class so all child class class can have acces . am new to java

Comment: Nice answer @imBollaveni

Comment: @JithinEzio declare wait and driver as static variables in the parent class. so that you can use them in all your child classes. Ex: static WebDriver driver;
static WebDriverWait wait;